# Deprecated: Hibernate setHint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

According to the Hibernate 5.2 [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setHint-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-), Hibernate Query setHint is deprecated now. Is there an alternative to that now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll to the top of the document, you can see that using `org.hibernate.Query` is deprecated since 5.2. You can use `org.hibernate.query.Query` instead. [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setHint-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)'s the new documentation.